# error because bytes are not able to be encoded?

Tags: python, byte

So I am using this public program to parse this byte data, but I am getting the error that the "bytes" object I am parsing has no attribute 'encode' what is going on and how to I fix it?

```
     62         for j in range(4):
     63             b = f.read(1)
---> 64             b = b.encode('hex').upper()
     65             tmpHex = b + tmpHex
     66         tmpHex = ''

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I have tried to replace encode with something else but I end up getting another error which is on line 65 above saying that b and tmpHex cannot be concatenated. How do I solve this?

I could not include all the code because stackoverflow said I had too much code and too little writing.

Link to full code is below:
https://github.com/normanvolt/blockchain-parser/blob/master/blockchain-parser.py

```
import os
import datetime
import hashlib

def HexToInt(s):
    t = ''
    if s == '':
        r = 0
    else:
        t = '0x' + s
        r = int(t,16)
    return r

def reverse(input):
    L = len(input)
    if (L % 2) != 0:
        return None
    else:
        Res = ''
        L = L // 2
        for i in range(L):
            T = input[i*2] + input[i*2+1]
            Res = T + Res
            T = ''
        return (Res);

def merkle_root(lst): # https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7eb080a67398f648c1709e41890f8c44
    sha256d = lambda x: hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(x).digest()).digest()
    hash_pair = lambda x, y: sha256d(x[::-1] + y[::-1])[::-1]
    if len(lst) == 1: return lst[0]
    if len(lst) % 2 == 1:
        lst.append(lst[-1])
    return merkle_root([hash_pair(x,y) for x, y in zip(*[iter(lst)]*2)])

dirA = 'd:/_blocks/' # Directory where blk*.dat files are stored
#dirA = sys.argv[1]
dirB = 'd:/_hash/' # Directory where to save parsing results
#dirA = sys.argv[2]

fList = os.listdir(dirA)
fList = [x for x in fList if (x.endswith('.dat') and x.startswith('blk'))]
fList.sort()

for i in fList:
    nameSrc = i
    nameRes = nameSrc.replace('.dat','.hash')
    resList = []
    a = 0
    t = dirA + nameSrc
    resList.append('Start ' + t + ' in ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    print ('Start ' + t + ' in ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    f = open(t,'rb')
    tmpHex = ''
    fSize = os.path.getsize(t)
    while f.tell() != fSize:
        for j in range(4):
            b = f.read(1)
            b = b.encode('hex').upper()
            tmpHex = b + tmpHex
        tmpHex = ''
        for j in range(4):
            b = f.read(1)
            b = b.encode('hex').upper()
            tmpHex = b + tmpHex
        resList.append('Block size = ' + tmpHex)
        tmpHex = ''
        tmpPos3 = f.tell()
        while f.tell() != tmpPos3 + 80:
            b = f.read(1)
            b = b.encode('hex').upper()
            tmpHex = tmpHex + b
        tmpHex = tmpHex.decode('hex')
        tmpHex = hashlib.new('sha256', tmpHex).digest()
        tmpHex = hashlib.new('sha256', tmpHex).digest()
        tmpHex = tmpHex.encode('hex')
        tmpHex = tmpHex.upper()
        tmpHex = reverse(tmpHex)
        resList.append('SHA256 hash of the current block hash = ' + tmpHex)
        f.seek(tmpPos3,0)
        tmpHex = ''
        for j in range(4):
            b = f.read(1)
            b = b.encode('hex').upper()
            tmpHex = b + tmpHex
        resList.append('Version number = ' + tmpHex)
        tmpHex = ''
        for j in range(32):
            b = f.read(1)
            b = b.encode('hex').upper()
            tmpHex = b + tmpHex
        resList.append('SHA256 hash of the previous block hash = ' + tmpHex)
        tmpHex = ''
        for j in range(32):
            b = f.read(1)
            b = b.encode('hex').upper()
            tmpHex = b + tmpHex
        resList.append('MerkleRoot hash = ' + tmpHex)
        MerkleRoot = tmpHex
        tmpHex = ''
        for j in range(4):
            b = f.read(1)
            b = b.encode('hex').upper()
            tmpHex = b + tmpHex
        resList.append('Time stamp > ' + tmpHex)
        tmpHex = ''
        for j in range(4):
            b = f.read(1)
            b = b.encode('hex').upper()
            tmpHex = b + tmpHex
        resList.append('Difficulty = ' + tmpHex)
        tmpHex = ''
        for j in range(4):
            b = f.read(1)
            b = b.encode('hex').upper()
            tmpHex = b + tmpHex
        resList.append('Random number > ' + tmpHex)
        tmpHex = ''
        b = f.read(1)
        bInt = int(b.encode('hex'),16)
        c = 0
        if bInt < 253:
            c = 1
            tmpHex = b.encode('hex').upper()
        if bInt == 253: c = 3
        if bInt == 254: c = 5
        if bInt == 255: c = 9
        for j in range(1,c):
            b = f.read(1)
            b = b.encode('hex').upper()
            tmpHex = b + tmpHex
        txCount = int(tmpHex,16)
        resList.append('Transactions count = ' + str(txCount))
        resList.append('')
        tmpHex = ''
        tmpPos1 = 0
        tmpPos2 = 0
        RawTX = ''
        tx_hashes = []
        for k in range(txCount):
            tmpPos1 = f.tell()
            for j in range(4):
                b = f.read(1)
                b = b.encode('hex').upper()
                tmpHex = b + tmpHex
            resList.append('transactionVersionNumber = ' + tmpHex)
            RawTX = reverse(tmpHex)
            tmpHex = ''
```

I had to reduce the code because I had too much code and not enough details.

Comment: Have you tried using `decode()` instead of `encode()`, maybe?

Comment: when I do I get the following error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 0: invalid start byte` @GreenCloakGuy Referring to the same line which had the original error.